# Cropping activity's saving action result in the app Gallery's ANR

Tags: android

I wrote an app with a button to invoke the activity to take a picture with the method `startActivityForResult`. When `onActivityResult` is called, the app turns to the cropping activity to crop the image I just took with also the method `startActivityForResult`. But when I save it, the gallery app always stops, returning Application not Responding Error, which leads to the parameter resultCode in `onActivityResult` method being **0**, which is `RESULT_CANCELED`.

The code is just `onCreate()`, `onActivityResult()`, and the following variables:

```
public static final int TAKE_PHOTO = 1;

public static final int CROP_PHOTO = 2;

private Button takePhoto;

private ImageView picture;

private Uri imageUri;
```

onCreate():

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    takePhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.take_photo);
    picture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picture);
    takePhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //init File object, to save the image
            File outputImage = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "output_image.jpg");
            try{
                if(outputImage.exists()){
                    outputImage.delete();
                }
                outputImage.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            imageUri = Uri.fromFile(outputImage);

            Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PHOTO);
        }
    });
```

onActivityResult():

```
switch (requestCode){
        case TAKE_PHOTO:
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Intent intent = new Intent("com.android.camera.action.CROP");
                intent.setDataAndType(imageUri, "image/*");
                intent.putExtra("scale", true);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_PHOTO);
            }
            break;

        case CROP_PHOTO:
            Log.d("MainActivity", "CROP_PHOTO_IN, result code : " + resultCode);
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                Log.d("MainActivity", "CROP_PHOTO_OK");
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri));
                    picture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    Log.d("MainActivity", "PHOTO_SET");
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
```

relevant log:

06-28 10:30:35.750    1682-1694/? W/CameraCaptureSession﹕ Session 0: The camera device was already closed:
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: CameraDevice was already closed
at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.checkIfCameraClosedOrInError(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1482)
            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:677)
            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:328)
            at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.finalize(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:561)
            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:191)
            at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:174)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-28 10:30:38.200      483-561/? W/AudioTrack﹕ AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by client
06-28 10:30:38.205    1589-1782/? D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null
06-28 10:30:38.205    1589-1782/? W/CropActivity﹕ cannot open region decoder for file: file:///storage/emulated/0/output_image.jpg
    java.io.IOException: Image format not supported
            at android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder.nativeNewInstance(Native Method)
            at android.graphics.BitmapRegionDecoder.newInstance(BitmapRegionDecoder.java:124)
            at com.android.gallery3d.filtershow.crop.CropActivity$BitmapIOTask.doInBackground(CropActivity.java:483)
            at com.android.gallery3d.filtershow.crop.CropActivity$BitmapIOTask.doInBackground(CropActivity.java:355)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
06-28 10:30:38.206    1589-1782/? D/skia﹕ --- SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null

Also, sometimes this doesn't happen, which for me is not predictable.
But it always result in `FileNotFoundException` caused by permission denial.
I added the uses-permission, both read and write, not inside the application label. It didn't help.

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find a solution for it?

Comment: @Sandra not yet. You?

Comment: No, I didn't find a solution. Eventually I ended up using a support library for the cropping of the images: https://github.com/jdamcd/android-crop. But I must warn you, this library has a bug when cropping images with orientation different than 0, which you must handle yourself. The solution can be found in the discussions in the "issues" section. Whether it's going to be implemented in the next releases of the library, I don't know, but I hope so. Other than that it works good.

Comment: thanks for the heads up.